# 3 Function plus Main Function C Program calculating and displaying a Factorial

Tags: c++, for-loop, parameter-passing, factorial, modular-design

The first function needs to get the number and pass it back to main, this value then needs to be passed into a second function that calculates the factorial and passes that value back to main with the result being printed in the third and final function.

The program calculates the factorial of a number that is input. I need to keep the for loop. I'm not sure what's going wrong, I get garbage values back, so I think I'm losing a value somewhere or not storing a value.

Also any general help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void GetData(int &x)
{
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &x);

    return;
}

int Factorial(int x)
{
    int factorial = 1;
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }

    return(x);
}

void PrintResults(int factorial)
{
    printf("The factorial = %d\n", factorial);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int x, factorial;

    GetData(x);

    Factorial(x);


    PrintResults(factorial);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `int Factorial(int x)` should return `factorial`, not `x`. And then do something with the return value instead of discarding it. Actually this code is full of bugs. Try compiling with `-Wall` on the command line.

Comment: and `Factorial(x);` --> `factorial = Factorial(x);`

Comment: and `void GetData(int &x)` is not C but C++.

Comment: and maybe you should get hands on a good C textbook.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that my lecturer is using Pass by Ref in a simpler form from C++ due to time constraints on parts of this topic in the unit.

I know, I'm going to buy a textbook, I'm just trying some exercises from the lectures we just had.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage I've managed to get it running now, it had a few bugs. I'm learning and have found it difficult studying CS externally while working FT. Not many ppl to ask for help at odd study times, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should change your call to `GetData` to :

```
GetData(&x);
```

as you want to pass a pointer. Then, its declaration should change to :

```
void GetData(int *x)
{
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", x);
}
```

Then, you should return variable `factorial` instead of `x`. Change line :

```
return(x);
```

to :

```
return(factorial);
```

and consequently call `Factorial` function as follows :

```
factorial = Factorial(x);
```

as right now, variable `factorial` is uninitialized, and by passing it to `Factorial` you will be getting garbage, as you said.

Comment: We're not up to pointers yet in the unit I'm studying, I'll keep that in mind though. As soon as I posted this I realised I forgot the call to Factorial you mentioned, thanks. Not going to lie, this modular programming topic has been the hardest part of the unit so far and I'm having a bit of trouble keeping track of values/variables in this section.

Comment: @C.Jackson but what I showed is passing by reference... I think this is what you tried to do as well, but did it wrong...

Comment: what I used was passing by reference I'm pretty sure, but a simpler C++ version according to our lecturer.

Comment: @C.Jackson Ok, I do not know C++... I answered it for C.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to put that part in the body of my question. The lecturer decided to use a simpler Pass by Ref from C++ due to time constraints/or us not reaching a certain part of the unit yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @C.Jackson you are welcome! If your problem is solved you can accept one of the answers, so that the question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void GetData(int &x)
{
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d%*c", &x);
}

int Factorial(int x)
{
    int factorial = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }

    return(factorial);
}

void PrintResult(int factorial)
{
    printf("The factorial = %d\n", factorial);
}

int main()
{
    int x; // Declaring x
    GetData(x); // Initializing x
    int factorial = Factorial(x); // Using x to compute factorial and store result in variable 
    PrintResult(factorial); // Print that variable
    return 0;
}
```

I removed `return;` in GetData because void functions implicitly return.

Comment: Curious to know why downvote, and opened to any constructive advises